# How to have a consortium with 1 organization in a network with two organizations?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am setting up a server composed of two organizations (3 later), as shown in the following link : https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/network/network.html

However, the consortium must not contain the two organizations (Org1 and Org2) but only organization 1 (Org1) as shown in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9pI7.jpg

In my configtx.yaml file, I set the SampleConsortium value as a follow:

```
Profiles:

    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    # - *Org2
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

So I define a consortium with a single organization: Org2.

However, when instantiating my channel with the line of code

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example. com-cert.pem
```

The screen displays an error telling me: Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Attempted to include a member which is not in the consortium

Do you have an idea to generate my channel by having only one organization in my consortium?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers :)

PS : This is my first project with hyperledger fabric, so I am still "new" with this technology. However, it seems to me that there is no indication that a consortium should not have at least 2 organizations.

Comment: Remove Org2 details from TwoOrgschannel Profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to comment Org2 from TwoOrgsChannel profile. then you will be able to create my channel once this is done you can add Org2 by updating the channel config for further details you can refer read the docs https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, your solution worked. However, I can only add the Org1 Organization in my channel. If I comment on the Org2 line, an error

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'mychannel', could not succesfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

While my **configtx.yaml** file looks like this:

```
Profiles:

    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
               # - *Org1
                 - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Comment: I solved the problem myself. I was running the command to create Channel via peer0.org1 (which is the default)! So I specified the command variable by putting the one of the user peer0.org2 ! And it worked!